# Python - mock function and assert exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest, fastapi

I built an API with FastAPI that interacts with DynamoDB.
In the beginning of my journey in Test Driven Development, I have doubts about what to mock.
This is the get method, main.py:

```
router = FastAPI()

@router.get("/{device_id}")
def get_data(request: Request, device_id: str, query: DataQuery = Depends(DataQuery.depends)):
    da_service = DaService()
    try:
        start_time, end_time = DaService.validate_dates(query.start, query.end)
        return 'OK'
    except WrongDataFormat as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Internal Server Error')
```

In the test file I started by creating the success test, test_main.py:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from unittest import mock
from utils.exceptions import WrongDataFormat
from endpoints.datalake import router

client = TestClient(router)

def test_success_response():
    with mock.patch('endpoints.datalake.DataApiService.get_datalake_data'):
        response = client.get('/xxxxx', params = {'start': '1629886483', 'end': '1629886504'})
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert isinstance(response.json(), dict)
```

Now I want to create the test for when the exception WrongDataFormat is returned, but I'm not succeeding... This is what I have right now:

```
def test_exception_response_():
    response = client.get('/xxxxx', params = {'2021-08-28', 'end': '2021-12-25'})
    assert response.status_code == 400
```

How can I mock the function main.validate_dates to return the exception WrongDataFormat and assert it correctly?

Comment: Is it `da.validate_dates` or `DaService.validate_dates` you want to patch? Either way, you probably want to patch `DaService` so that you can control the definition of `validate_dates`, or better yet, let `get_data` receive either an instance of something `DaService`-like, or a `DaService`-like class, as an argument, to avoid the need to use `mock.patch` at all.

Comment: You seem to want to create a test for `validate_dates`, not for the endpoint; the endpoint does not raise the exception, it returns a 400 response. Write a test to make sure that `validate_dates` raises an exception, then write a test that makes sure your endpoint returns a 400 when it does (be careful about mocking too much; suddenly you're just testing that your mocking library works, and not that your endpoint makes sense). Mocks often creates a dependency on the implementation and not the interface itself, which is what you want to interact with and test.

Comment: @chepner From what I understood, inside patch it goes the path of the functioncalled not where it's defined... I didn't get what was your suggestion, sorry

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you for the reply! To test the 400 the validate_dates needs to return the Exception, how would you do that?

Comment: @Raphael First I'd send invalidate dates. What is an invalid date will be defined by what the `validate_dates` function does; that way you test the behaviour and not the implementation, so if the implementation changes, you still have a test that makes sure that whatever you think of as invalid dates still holds as a test. The test should test the requirement for the endpoint and not the implementation. If you want to use a mock to generate the exception because it seems "cleaner" (it will seem that way, but it's a fallacy in my experience), you do what you do - but you don't assert..

Comment: the exception, you test that the response from the endpoint is as expected as when the exception happens. So you test that the response has a status code of 400, not that the exception was raised.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you very much again for your help! I understood 100% of what you said and it made sense to me, I changed the test_exception_response() code. However when I run it now, it returns: FAILED tests/test_main.py::test_exception_response - fastapi.exceptions.HTTPException

Comment: @MatsLindh it seems like the exception is thrown before the assertion gets evaluated, marking test as failed...

Comment: I think the reason might be because you're adding the router to the testclient and not the app itself. Since you're creating testclient with the router, you see the exception raised (it's an httpexception, not the internal exception) instead of the actual response. I'd go with `TestClient(app)` instead unless you have a good reason to only add the router instead of testing the API of your application.

Comment: You're right, it works with TestClient(app)!!

Comment: @MatsLindh, can you please check this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68988800/python-fastapi-apirouter-how-to-unit-test-exception). It is also mine because I tried all day to solve the problem with no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test the status code and message of a response you have to use `TestClient(app)` where `app` is the FastAPI application. Converting the exception into the appropriate response is the task of the application, not the router (which is what you're testing with).

```
client = TestClient(app)
```

This way you can test the API of your application (which is the most useful surface to test, imho).