# How to unit test Exception in APIRouter (not FastAPI)

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, fastapi

I'm having difficulties doing the unit tests for the function *get_data* in **main.py**:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/{device_id}")
def get_data(request: Request, device_id: str, query: DataQuery = Depends(DataQuery.depends)):
    data_service = DataApiService()
    try:
        datetime_start_timestamp, datetime_end_timestamp = data_service.validate_dates(query.start, query.end)
        df_results = data_service.get_datalake_data(device_id, datetime_start_timestamp, datetime_end_timestamp)
        return df_results
    except EndDataLowerStartDate as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Internal Server Error')
```

This is the solution I have, **test_main.py**:

```
from main import router
client = TestClient(router)

def test_get_data_EndDataLowerStartDate():
    mock.patch('main.DataApiService', side_effect = EndDataLowerStartDate)
    response = client.get('/xxxxx', params = {'start': '2021-12-31', 'end': '2021-01-01'})
    assert response.status_code == 400
    assert response.json() == {'detail': 'End date {0} is lower or equal to start date {1}'.format(end, start)}
```

However, the test only works if I replace in **main.py**:

`router = APIRouter()` by `app = FastAPI()`

and in **test_main.py**:

`client = TestClient(router)` by `client = TestClient(app)`.

Otherwise I get the error:

> FAILED test_main.py::test_get_data_EndDataLowerStartDate - fastapi.exceptions.HTTPException

If I don't change anything, when I locally make the request, it returns:

> AttributeError: 'FastAPI' object has no attribute
> 'default_response_class'

It is like the exception is raised before it is assert... I cannot change **main.py** because it is a bigger application inicially built this way. I'm sorry if I was unclear but I would like to know how to make the test pass. Do you have an idea of how I could solve this?

Comment: Since you're using the router directly the exception is never converted into a response (this happens in the FastAPI application, not in the router). You have to assert that the exception is raised in this case.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you once again! You're very kind! Would it be something like: `client = TestClient(router) class TestData(unittest.TestCase):     def test_get_data_EndDataLowerStartDate(self):         mock.patch('main.DataApiService.validate_dates', side_effect = EndDataLowerStartDate)         self.assertRaises(EndDataLowerStartDate, client.get('/xxxxx', params = {'start': '2021-12-31', 'end': '2021-01-01'}))`